# How to implement a SearchController with a SearchResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

Hello I am trying to implement a SearchController into my application however, my application has different tabs in which I would like them to see the search functionality. I have added a button to the NavBar and each of these tabs has a main controller view which includes this code. Unfortunately when I try to search for something the table view does not display with the results. Thank you for your help! Please find the code below:

MainController:

```
// set up search:
func setUpSearch(){
self.searchDataSource = DataTableViewController() // UIViewController, contains all functions for tableview plus outlet of tableview
self.searchController = UISearchController.init(searchResultsController: searchDataSource)
self.searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
         self.searchController?.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
         self.searchController?.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for people or places"
}


// user clicked on search button:
func searchButtonClicked(){
    self.searchController?.isActive = true
    self.searchController?.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    if let controller = self.searchController {
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using storyboard, you should use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` instead of `DataTableViewController()`

Comment: @3stud1ant3 that did the trick thank you for your idea!!!